# Help the Help Center

Tags: discussion, help-center

When I read through the help center recently, I was surprised how little some of the pages were related to this site, one example being [How to not be a spammer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/promotion), which looks like it comes from Stack Overflow with only the site name changed. Is it possible to change big parts of the help center, as I don't think self-promotion is really even possible here or is it not possible to change the sites in the help center?